# Cannot find element by class attribute using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I cannot find element by class attribute using selenium from this [site](https://djinni.co/login). Unfortunately I get an NoSuchElementException. But at the same time I am sure that this element exists on the page:

```
<div class="page-header mb-3">
   <h1>Log In to Djinni</h1>
</div>
```

Here code of my program:

```
dr = webdriver.Chrome()
dr.get("https://djinni.co/login")
dr.maximize_window()
header = dr.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "page-header mb-3") #NoSuchElementException
print(header.text)
```

Can anyone tell me what the reason is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake.

You are looking for the class ***page-header mb-3*** - this is two classes, ***page-header*** and ***mb-3***

If you specify either of these classes instead of both it will work.

```
dr = webdriver.Chrome()
dr.get("https://djinni.co/login")
dr.maximize_window()
header = dr.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "page-header") #This works
print(header.text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such a stupid mistake, it's a shame that I spent so much time and didn't find the reason myself. If I'm not mistaken, the BeautifulSoup library allows you to search for several class names at once, which is why I thought that there could be no mistake here. Now it’s also clear why some class names worked and others didn’t.